# 24/7 Solar panel + battery to power a Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: pi-zero-w, battery

I need to create a system to have a remote bees monitoring.

In this place I haven't the electrical energy. Basically I need to monitor some sensors (5 temperature and humidity sensors).

I'm not expert electronic side (I'm a sw developer) and I would like to understand if it's possible (or already exist) a way to use a solar panel + a battery to power (24/7) a Raspberry Pi Zero W.

I'm not able to found some example projetc (with a list of necessary components a schema to connect all).

First of all...Is it possible? In case, can you share some ideas or projects example?
For me it's not clear, for example, the capacity of the battery, the size of the solar panel and the way to connect all to have the power 24/7... basically  for me nothing is clear :)

Comment: This can be a starting point, but anyway you need a soldering iron to build something reliable: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/power-esp32-esp8266-solar-panels-battery-level-monitoring/

Comment: Welcome -- but I think you can see from the answer(s) that this is not the best place to ask about this, partially because the Pi is really only tangential to the question.  I'd suggest our larger sibling site, [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, BUT no one is going to design it for you.

Actually you would be better NOT using a Pi (even the Zero is power hungry) but use a microcontroller (like am Arduino - which is designed to permit low power use) to collect your data.